# Need help creating a Commerce Order from Commerce Customer shipping profile

Tags: commerce

I am looking for a way for our admin users on a Drupal Commerce site to look up customer profiles from previous orders, and upon looking at a specific customer profile, provide a button that allows then to create an order for that customer. This use case is for a call center.

So far, I have tried using Button Field to call a rule component but I have having problems writing the rule.

Looking up previous orders and creating a new order with information for the shipping profile attached would also be a viable alternative.

Any suggestions regarding approach or use of modules would be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Things like this, is much easier to accomplish with a bit of custom code. You could add a form on the order view page, with the order as the context. This can be done by using `hook_commerce_order_view`.

All you really need to do, in the submit handler would be something like this.

```
$old_order //
$new_order = commerce_order_new();
$new_order->uid = $old_order->uid;
$new_order->commerce_shipping_profile = $old_order->commerce_shipping_profile;
commerce_order_save($new_order);
$form_state['redirect'] = 'admin/commerce/order/' . $new_order->order_id . '/edit';
```

The code above is from memory, should be in a form submit handler and is written from memory, but should work, if I remembered correctly. As you can see, it's pretty simple to accomplish.

Comment: thanks for the reply, our team will try it out shortly and post our results